# How to Enable Macro settings thru code?

Tags: c#, powerpoint, office-interop

I have created a Macro in a Powerpoint Presentation using the following code. When running this small piece of code I was getting an exception " programmatic access to visual basic project is not trusted". I know this can be resolved by changing the Trust Center Settings in options. But can anyone help me how I can change these settings thru code. ike any powerpoint interop APIs?? pl suggest.. Thanks in advance.

My sample code:

```
PowerPoint.Application oPPT = new PowerPoint.Application();
oPPT.Visible = Office.MsoTriState.msoTrue;

//Add New Presentation
PowerPoint.Presentations oPresSet = oPPT.Presentations;
PowerPoint.Presentation oPres = oPresSet.Add(Office.MsoTriState.msoTrue);

//Add Slides to the Presentation
PowerPoint.Slides oSlides = oPres.Slides;
PowerPoint.Slide oSlide = oSlides.Add(1, PowerPoint.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutTitle);

VBComponent vbc =  oPres.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule);
string code = "sub VBAMacro()\r\n" + "ActivePresentation.Close\n" + "End Sub";
vbc.CodeModule.AddFromString(code);
```

Comment: I doubt you can do this. The whole point of not allowing untrusted code to run without the user's permission is to keep malicious code from running. If the malicious code could allow itself to run without asking the user first, that would sort of defeat the whole purpose, don't you think?

Comment: I have little knowledge in those security policies. But don't it restricts a genuine user also from not running a Macro in a presentation in automated way?

Comment: No. The user can allow the code to run (if they know what it's doing) by changing the options (as you mentioned). But doing it in code would allow it to be done without the user's consent, which means the code could do bad things. People used to write malware all the time in VBA macros; that's why the security setting was established in the first place.

Comment: So, there is no other way to enable these settings except doing it thru UI?

Comment: I've said that twice now; will saying it a third time help? :) No, you cannot change this without doing it through the UI. If you could, so could any malevolent code, and then it could do bad things to the user's computer.

Comment: well, Thanks for the third time :) Still it didn't help. I gotta do a hll lot of work to get it done thru UI :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, that setting is just stored in a registry key, so you could do something like this, but you will need to run with permissions to access that registry key.  I did a basic test and it seemed to work on my machine.

```
using (var key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\PowerPoint\Security",true))
{
    int origVal = (int)key.GetValue("AccessVBOM", 0);
    if (origVal != 1)
        key.SetValue("AccessVBOM", 1);


    PowerPoint.Application oPPT = new PowerPoint.Application();
    oPPT.Visible = Office.MsoTriState.msoTrue;

    //Add New Presentation
    PowerPoint.Presentations oPresSet = oPPT.Presentations;
    PowerPoint.Presentation oPres = oPresSet.Add(Office.MsoTriState.msoTrue);

    //Add Slides to the Presentation
    PowerPoint.Slides oSlides = oPres.Slides;
    PowerPoint.Slide oSlide = oSlides.Add(1, PowerPoint.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutTitle);

    VBComponent vbc = oPres.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule);
    string code = "sub VBAMacro()\r\n" + "ActivePresentation.Close\n" + "End Sub";
    vbc.CodeModule.AddFromString(code);

    if (origVal != 1)
    {
        key.SetValue("AccessVBOM", origVal);
    }

    key.Close();
}
```

Comment: As long as you can run code external to PowerPoint and run it before PPT starts, you can change the settings (as you're doing in the example, of course).  Last time I checked, PPT reads its registry settings on startup; if the user makes any changes via UI, those are stored internally and written back to the registry immediately, and the whole works is written back at shutdown.  Anything you write to the reg while ppt is open will be ignored while PPT is alive and overwritten when it quits.

Comment: I agree with that, PowerPoint does read the setting at startup, but based on the code sample provided (creating the new Application) I assumed it was being done outside of PowerPoint.

Comment: yes, exactly so.  That's why I made sure to include "as you're doing in the example".  But a "gotcha" just occurred to me.  PowerPoint only allows one instance of itself, so even requesting New PowerPoint Application will give you a reference to an already running instance of PPT, so you'd need to take steps to guard against that if you're counting on making registry settings work and stick.  There's just no end to the fun.  ;-)